# Как в существующем PDF документе создать внутреннюю ссылку на страницу в этом же документе Python

Tags: python, c#, pdf, itext, fpdf

Есть PDF документ и мне необходимо создать внутренние ссылки на соответствующие страницы в нем. Я пробовал библиотеку fpdf, но, на сколько я понял, в ней нет возможности читать существующие файлы, а только создавать новые и добавлять ссылки. Я много изучаю библиотек, но так и не могу найти то, что мне нужно. Слышал еще про PDFlib, но в документации тоже не нашел информации как создавать внутренние ссылки на страницы. Если вызнаете решения на других языках, то также жду ваших примеров и советов.

Comment: У pyfpdf есть метод add_link: https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf/blob/cb3340806c140b6e63eb4ce9d6230be84fba456e/fpdf/fpdf.py#L656 пример https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf/blob/cb3340806c140b6e63eb4ce9d6230be84fba456e/tutorial/tuto6.py#L91

Comment: Есть ли возможность, используя эту библиотеку читать существующие файлы? Я, к сожалению, этой возможности не нашёл. Я был бы вам благодарен, если бы вы мне объяснили или откорректировали мои знания, если я не прав. Спасибо!

Comment: пожалуйста, не плодите однотипные вопросы (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1445820/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-fpdf)

Comment: Насколько я помню, у pdf очень непростой и закрытый формат, поэтому редакторы под него сложно найти, а с библиотеками с такой функциональности еще сложнее. Не нашел в репозитории pyfpdf функционала для редактирования - только создания новых pdf. что и написано в FAQ https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md: `FPDF (and PyFPDF) is a library with low-level primitives to easily generate PDF documents.`

Comment: Вот, вроде у Chart Explorers получилось, с помощью PyPDF2 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1a91QAVZME

Comment: Да, правда он сохранил все добавленные ссылки в новый документ, но что мешает просто удалить первоначальный, а новый переименовать?

Comment: Спасибо, Сергей, параллельно с вашим ответом нашел документацию аналогичную вашему ответу. Всех благодарю!